# Camera taking too long to open in Redmi Note 9

Tags: ram, camera

I have Redmi Note 9 which is about 1 year old but everything is up to date.
Now the problem is that whenever I open the camera a black screen appears and it takes 15 seconds to open it and as I tap the shutter button the screen freezes with the photo and after another 15 seconds it updates.
I have tried everything on the internet including:

1. Restarting the camera
2. Restarting the phone.
3. Clearing the camera data.
4. Restoring camera settings to default.

I suspect that it is the problem in the memory as I see that only 700-800mb memory is available every time out of 4gb. But every other app just runs fine.
So how can I fix that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try to check `adb logcat` if any errors are logged that could be related to this problem (requires to enable Developer menu and adb on device as well as install "minimal adb" or adb from Android SDK on the PC side).

Comment: Can you try any 3rd party camera app?